# What is the best way to port from Objective-C to C++?

Tags: c++, objective-c

I have no Objective-C experience whatsoever but have a strong C++ background. Is there an automated tool/script or, worst case, some manual method using some excellent reference to port code written in Objective-C to C++? What are the difficulties involved?

Edit:
I'm told the code uses Objective-C fairly trivially. It's an iPhone app that probably doesn't use much in the way of OS-level UI. The C++ version is meant for a non-Apple platform where GNUStep is not an option, so Objective-C++ is not an option.

Comment: Have you got that the right way around? You have a strong C++ background, but you want to port stuff *to* C++?

Comment: @Cebjyre, He doesn't know Obj-C enough to read it and translate into C++.  He can, however, correct C++ bugs when they pop up due to faulty translation.  At least, that's what I speculate.

Comment: I'll accept that as a possibility, but I'd say the conversion process would be likely to introduce more bugs in buggy code, so a tool to convert known C++ code into Obj C code would be handy from a learning perspective.

Answer (score 7):

I worked on same problem. And have some solutions:

- Microsoft now offers its own Objective C "bridge", albeit only for UWP apps.

  https://github.com/Microsoft/WinObjC
- In 2007 I tried to support Objective-C in Visual Studio and wrote my own ObjC runtime, but I do not have more time for writing parser for it. If you have, you can :)

  http://code.google.com/p/qobjc/
- I wrote the basic functionality of Foundation Framework in C++.  In this case, you need to port manually; your code will be on C++ but it will be like on Objective-C. This library worked on iPhone.

  http://code.google.com/p/dcocoa/

Answer (score 3):

There are no automated tools that I'm aware of. The dynamic nature of Objective-C is very hard to translate to C++, so quite a bit of brain effort is going to be required for all but trivial Objective-C code. Are you willing to stay on OS X (or keep the GNUStep dependency if you're one of the few people using Objective-C on an OS besides OS X)? If so, the easiest approach is to use [Objective-C++](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocCPlusPlus.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH10-SW1) to build a bridge beteen the Objective-C and C++ code. Objective-C++ is an Apple extension to Objective-C and the GCC compiler that allows you to mix Objective-C and C++ code. You can thus create Objective-C objects that call or reference (but not inherit from) C++ objects and you can send Objective-C messages to Objective-C instances from within C++ code.

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C was just a pre-processor (and a runtime library). You'll find more problems in porting all the libraries than the end-user code.
Nil-eating behavior is going to be fun when translating.

You are likely to start seeing bad design in all c++ code after using Objective-C frameworks for a while.

Answer (score 0):

While not fully feature complete, Clang ships with a transpiler than can rewrite Objective-C/C++ to C++, using the `-rewrite-objc` flag (https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangCommandLineReference.html#cmdoption-clang-rewrite-objc).

I have a blog post where you can read more about this approach and its limitations: https://www.jviotti.com/2023/12/01/understanding-objective-c-by-transpiling-it-to-cpp.html.

While the re-writer is not perfect, it definitely helps a lot, and we make heavy use of it at Postman.